# Seforim on Suffering

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, jewish-books, suffering

Besides sefer Yov and its commentaries, are there any seforim on a jewish understanding of suffering? I'd like to see a book in which there is rabbinic sources and/or insights regarding this in a way one could understand and comprehend this difficult toppic which affects people in different ways in life.

Related: [Suffering of the righteous](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57851/suffering-of-the-righteous-kabbalistic-interpretation) and [Punishment vs suffering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109711/punishment-vs-suffering)

Comment: https://books.google.com/books/about/Out_of_the_Whirlwind.html?id=KZxeMJ4kojMC

Comment: See Gemara Brochos 5a-b for yissurin shel ahava

Comment: Daas Torah sourcebook

Answer (score 3):

[Pain is a Reality, Suffering is a Choice](https://mosaicapress.com/product/pain-is-a-reality-suffering-is-a-choice/) is a book written by someone who lost their daughter at a very young age after their child was severely ill for years.
It is a very well-written book from many different angles and all sourced on how to view suffering.

[image]